# Crash due to optional string in swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I was converting the timestamp to time but my timeStampToDate is giving this output "Optional(1476775542548)" due to which it crashes.So how i can remove this Optional string.

```
    let timeStampToDate = (String(describing:merchant.post["timestamp"])) as String
    let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")
    merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)

    init?(jsonDate: String) {
    //        "/Date(1487058855745)/"

    let prefix = "/Date("
    let suffix = ")/"
    let scanner = Scanner(string: jsonDate)

    // Check prefix:
    guard scanner.scanString(prefix, into: nil)  else { return nil }

    // Read milliseconds part:
    var milliseconds : Int64 = 0
    guard scanner.scanInt64(&milliseconds) else { return nil }
    // Milliseconds to seconds:
    var timeStamp = TimeInterval(milliseconds)/1000.0

    // Read optional timezone part:
    var timeZoneOffset : Int = 0
    if scanner.scanInt(&timeZoneOffset) {
        let hours = timeZoneOffset / 100
        let minutes = timeZoneOffset % 100
        // Adjust timestamp according to timezone:
        timeStamp += TimeInterval(3600 * hours + 60 * minutes)
    }

    // Check suffix:
    guard scanner.scanString(suffix, into: nil) else { return nil }

    // Success! Create NSDate and return.
    self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
}
```

Comment: use optional Binding.This has been answered multiple time .

Comment: It is not working by using optional binding i already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapped the optional value that you getting from `merchant.post["timestamp"]`.

```
if let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] as? String {
    print(timeStampToDate)
    let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate)))/")
    merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)
}
```

**Note:** If it is still not works then you need to show us declaration of `Date(jsonDate:)`

**Edit:** If it is not string then try like this way

```
if let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] {
    print(timeStampToDate)
    let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate)))/")
    merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")` (because the OP said that the `timeStampToDate` is set correctly)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Check the question OP saying "but my timeStampToDate is giving this output "Optional(1476775542548)"" So it means timeStampToDate is optional

Comment: @NiravD it never go into if condition.

Comment: @RahulGupta Then it is not the String, it is number. try like `if let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] as? Double {
    let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")`

Comment: @RahulGupta Have you try by converting it to number like my above comment.

Comment: @NiravD yes i tried it is giving this o/p for timeStampTodate 1476775542548.0 and when i pass it to the jsonDate it leads to crash in the second line.

Comment: @RahulGupta Then you need to show us what is `jsonDate` function, Show the declaration of it.

Comment: @NiravD I had change the double to Int and it worked.. :)

Comment: @RahulGupta Like `if let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] as? Int { let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")` This one is also work `if let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] { let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")`

Comment: @RahulGupta Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use guard let to wrap the optional value. Replace your code with below code.

```
guard let timeStampToDate = merchant.post["timestamp"] as? String else {
  return
}

let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")
merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)
```

Comment: It is giving error. Non-void function should return a value in else return.

Answer (score 0):

```
let timeStampToDate = (String(describing:merchant.post["timestamp"])) as String
let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate!))/")
merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)
```

Edit

```
if let timeStampToDate = (String(describing:merchant.post["timestamp"])) as? String {
    let timeSt = Date(jsonDate:"/Date(\(timeStampToDate))/")
    merchantOpenLbl.text = Date().onlyTimee(date: timeSt!)
}
```

Comment: Its giving error. Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'.